# Find conditions over $U$ such that optimization over a convex cone generated by $U$ is equal to optimization over $U$.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, optimal-control

We considerer the following optimization problem
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{cl} \max\limits_{x\in\mathcal{C}} & f(x) \\[2pt]
\text{s.t.} & \mathcal{A}x-b \in K \end{array}   \right. \tag{1}
$$

where $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{A}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ are linear functions non-zero, $b\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$, $\mathcal{C}$ is a convex cone in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $K$ is a closed convex cone in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$.

**Question:** I need to find conditions over a set $U\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that if $\mathcal{C}$ is the convex cone generated by $U$, then  problem $(1)$ is equivalent to the following problem
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{cl} \max\limits_{x\in U} & f(x) \\[2pt]
\text{s.t.} & \mathcal{A}x-b \in K \end{array}   \right. \tag{2}
?$$

Comment: Without any condition on $f$??

Comment: @Magnusseen We can consider $f$ concave.